# Don't Save Session Cookies and Cache in Incognito Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, wordpress, browser-cache

Ok basically I'm using wordpress to make a website, and so I'd like to use Incognito mode to view the website as the visitor would see it (so I don't have to log off and then log back on to edit again), but the thing is Incognito mode saves session cookies/cache, so for example if I click accept on my cookies notice, incognito will remember for that session to not show that notice again. Is there any way for incognito to not store anything at all? So i dont have to close and reopen, instead I could just refresh and it would bring back the site with no data stored.